# One of subdomain VirtualHost cannot access on apache2

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualhost

Company purchased a new server device,

currently we need to migrate the old project to the new one,

while we adding virtual host into new apache,

one of the site cannot access, this just happen today.

the following site cannot access,

```
coltd.domain.mo
```

I am trying find out why and fix it.

Following status which checked earlier.

The `000-default.conf` file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port t>
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        #ServerName www.example.com
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName www.domain.mo
        DocumentRoot /var/www
</VirtualHost>
...
...
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName merch.domain.mo
        DocumentRoot /var/www/merch
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName coltd.domain.mo
        DocumentRoot /var/www/co_ltd
</VirtualHost>
```

some checking method from google

```
apache2 -v
---
Server version: Apache/2.4.48 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   2022-06-14T12:33:28
```

```
apache2ctl -S
---
VirtualHost configuration:
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server localhost (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost localhost (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost merch.domain.mo (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:70)
... 
# All other sites working fine
# Only coltd.domain.mo cannot access
... 
         port 80 namevhost coltd.domain.mo (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:74)

ServerRoot: "/etc/apache2"
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www/html"
Main ErrorLog: "/var/log/apache2/error.log"
Mutex watchdog-callback: using_defaults
Mutex default: dir="/var/run/apache2/" mechanism=default
Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults
PidFile: "/var/run/apache2/apache2.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="www-data" id=33 not_used
Group: name="www-data" id=33 not_used
```

```
 sudo systemctl status apache2
[sudo] password for webserver:
● apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Fri 2023-01-27 13:11:51 HKT; 36min ago
       Docs: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/
    Process: 1095322 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 1095326 (apache2)
      Tasks: 11 (limit: 11862)
     Memory: 19.1M
        CPU: 367ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/apache2.service
             ├─1095326 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
             ├─1095327 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
             ├─1095328 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
             ├─1095329 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
             ├─1095330 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
             ├─1095331 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
             ├─1095400 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
             ├─1095406 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
             ├─1095407 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
             ├─1095408 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
             └─1095409 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start

Jan 27 13:11:50 webserver-27 systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Jan 27 13:11:51 webserver-27 systemd[1]: Started The Apache HTTP Server.
```

1. The `*.domain.mo/coltd/` can be access, but not `coltd.domain.mo`,
2. Tried create new `coltd.domain.mo.conf` and test `a2dissite 000-default.conf` is working,
   (assume nothing wrong with `apache2`)
3. Checked `sudo apache2ctl configtest` result `syntax OK`,
4. restarted `sudo systemctl reload apache2` and `restart apache2`,

Hopefully found the reason,

we know should be separate all subdomain files, but we plan to do that on next step.

sadly currently small project still adding in `000-default.conf`.

Thanks all kinds help.